# Vídeo em HTML5 sem menu de contexto

Tags: jquery, html5, internet-explorer

Como desativar menu de contexto do botão da direita do mouse em vídeos, para não aparecer o menuzinho do vídeo?

```
$('#nome').contextmenu( function() {
    return false;
});
```

O código acima, mas não funciona no internet explorer, o vídeo fica com fonte inválida.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tente o código seguinte:

```
$('body').on('contextmenu', '#nome', function(e){ return false; });
```

> Fonte original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864321/194717

Comment: Conte se funcionou ou não funcionou.

Comment: Tá funcionando no chrome e no firefox, mas no ie não, já limpei os cookies e tudo e nada...fonte inválida..

Comment: Haha, excelente a resposta no SO ser do Zuul :)

Comment: há, funcionou sim, tava bugado...