# Remover menu de contexto de vídeo do Vimeo

Tags: html5, vimeo-api

Alguém saberia como remover o menu-context de vídeos do Vimeo pois la tem a opção de "salvar como" que salva meu vídeo, mesmo ele estando privado na minha conta a pessoa pode acessar depois com arquivo html que foi salvo, em alguns casos o vídeo é baixado para maquina da pessoa.

Tentei varias formas usando, javascript, JQuery e até AngularJs e nada de não mostrar o menu quando clico com o botão direito em cima do vídeo.

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia, fico feliz.

Segue o link de um video do vimeo no codepen para fazer teste.

http://codepen.io/bdougherty/pen/JgDfm

[Vídeo em HTML5 sem menu de contexto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12785/v%C3%ADdeo-em-html5-sem-menu-de-contexto)

Comment: Não é possível. Ou melhor, não é possível fazer isso em outro navegador que não seja o seu. Qualquer solução que pudéssemos te dar dependeria de você ser capaz de rodar código no navegador dos outros. Isso simplesmente não é possível (ou não deveria), por motivos óbvios de segurança. Se o Vimeo te deixasse fazer isso, ele teria uma vulnerabilidade de segurança chamada Cross-site scripting (XSS). Mais informações [nessa pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10921/ataques-xss-como-ocorre) (com uma excelente resposta)